# BigQuery Transfer Job of Firebase Crashlytics pending for a long time before start

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics

We are currently working on exporting Firebase Crashlytics data to BigQuery. 
However, there is consistently a waiting period preceding each transfer task, which typically spans from around 10 to 20 hours. The accompanying log message reads, "Files not ready to be processed yet." Here's a snapshot from the log:
[log snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCd2C.png)

You can observe from the logs that we scheduled the task to commence at 18:59 every day, but it did not initiate until 06:04 the following day. This delay occurs consistently with each daily task, but the duration of the delay varies, falling within the 10 to 20-hour range as previously mentioned.

We would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide an explanation for this situation or offer any advice on how to mitigate it. Additionally, we welcome any reference documents that may shed light on this issue.